# Can't switch to multi-user.target on Ubuntu 16.04.3 Desktop

Tags: 16.04, systemd, runlevel

Previously on multiple boxes with Ubuntu 16.04 running I've been using

```
sudo systemctl isolate multi-user.target
```

to go into CLI from the graphical.target mode. Or I have been using

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
```

to permanently let the boot process stop at multi-user mode. I can remember that it worked roughly half a year ago, but when I was trying it today, it didn't go on any of the two, to this date, fully up to date 16.04 systems I had available.

All I'm greeted with is a blinking non-responsive cursor. It's possible to switch TTY via <kbd>CTRL</kbd>+<kbd>ALT</kbd>+<kbd>F2</kbd> to be able to revert back to graphical.target mode, though, luckily.

I'm trying to figure out if this is a recent bug or if I have introduced some conflicting software. I'm not sure what to look for and where to look for it.

Both boxes are using the kernel version

```
4.4.0-134-generic #160-Ubuntu SMP Wed Aug 15 14:58:00 UTC 2018 x86_64 x86_64 x86_64 GNU/Linux
```

I would be so glad for any guidance or bug confirmation!

Answer (score 1):

I just had the same issue! Fixed it by using the command:

`systemctl enable getty@tty2`

It forces the machine to use tty2 by default on boot.

Hope this helps you as much as it helped me

Answer (score 0):

Mary Jane, my experience confirms yours. I have a half-dozen systems on my network which were configured to default to multi-user mode, and have continued to perform as intended for over two years now, still are, and appear uncompromised by regular apt-get-upd-upg cycles. However, after doing clean installs of Xubuntu 16.04.6 on two new machines, I get the following error response:

> *systemctl enable multi-user.target*
>
> The unit files have no installation config (WantedBy, RequiredBy,
>   Also, Alias settings in the [Install] section, and DefaultInstance for
>   template units). This means they are not meant to be enabled using
>   systemctl. Possible reasons for having this kind of units are: 1) A
>   unit may be statically enabled by being symlinked from another unit's 
>   .wants/ or .requires/ directory. 2) A unit's purpose may be to act as
>   a helper for some other unit which has    a requirement dependency on
>   it. 3) A unit may be started when needed via activation (socket, path,
>   timer,    D-Bus, udev, scripted systemctl call, ...). 4) In case of
>   template units, the unit is meant to be enabled with some    instance
>   name specified.

I then tested a completely fresh install on another system, and this time it appeared to accept the 'systemctl enable multi-user.target --force'. However, when I re-booted, it had completely bricked the partition (meaning, hard-reset, followed by blank screen). I have noticed that there have been almost no postings by people who have encountered this problem, and no solutions that I can find.

Subjectively speaking, just for the record, when Ubuntu decided to force its user community to accept systemd, and later, 'snapd', I stopped using any new ubuntu releases beyond 16.04. It was only recently, while considering moving up to 18.04, that I decided to re-evaluate 16.04.6, and the most recent version of 18.04. I'm very close to departing from Ubuntu entirely. This particular situation may have been the last-straw for me.