# How to launch tty automatically after start up?

Tags: 20.04, systemd, tty

I am using Ubuntu 20.04 and have done the following setup:

```
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target
sudo systemctl add-wants multi-user getty@tty1
```

and `/etc/securetty` has been created.

However, tty1 does not show after boot, unless <kbd>Ctrl</kbd>+<kbd>Alt</kbd>+<kbd>F1</kbd> is pressed.

Although `getty@tty1` wants `multi-user.target`, I saw `getty@tty1` before `multi-user.target` in `systemd-analyze` results. Is it correct?

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure whether you should add getty in add-wants, because it seems to make getty one of multi-user.target's dependencies.

I also met similar problems of no login screen showed when switching to multi-user.target. It could be related to GRUB configuration, as mentioned in these two posts:

[Ubuntu running only graphics mode and I cant change to text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382766/ubuntu-running-only-graphics-mode-and-i-cant-change-to-text-mode)

[Cannot boot after sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1099463/cannot-boot-after-sudo-systemctl-set-default-multi-user-target)

So basically `GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="quiet splash"` in `/etc/default/grub` forces the kernel to display a splash screen, so there seems to be no output. You could just change it to:
`GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT=""` without modifying getty to show the login console.

Then run `update-grub` to update GRUB

Comment: Hello. This has noting to do with the question that was asked.

Comment: I thought no TTY shown is caused by GRUB configurations instead of manually adding gettty service