# How to configure Ubuntu 22.04 to boot in console/text mode only and have a 80 column x 25 row screen

Tags: boot, command-line, display-resolution, text, mode

How to configure Ubuntu 22.04 to boot in console/text mode only and have an 80-column x 25-row full screen? This is for a legacy application

Running:
sudo systemctl set-default multi-user.target does get the system to boot in console mode but without changing the resolution.

I have tried editing 2 lines in `/etc/default/grub`

```
GRUB_CMDLINE_LINUX_DEFAULT="text nomodeset"
GRUB_TERMINAL=console
```

I have tried editing `/etc/default/console-setup`

```
# CONFIGURATION FILE FOR SETUPCON
# Consult the console-setup(5) manual page.

ACTIVE_CONSOLES="/dev/tty[1-6]"
CHARMAP="UTF-8"
CODESET="guess"
#FONTFACE="Fixed"
#FONTSIZE="8x16"
FONTFACE="TerminusBoldVGA"
FONTSIZE="8x14"
VIDEOMODE=
# The following is an example of how to use a braille font
# FONT='lat9w-08.psf.gz brl-8x8.psf'
```

Neither of these modifications makes any difference in the screen resolution.

Thank you in advance for your help
Charlie

Comment: What version of Ubuntu did you install.? It reads like you want server with no GUI.

Comment: `/etc/default/console-setup` is where it needs to happen, and the options will be rather limited.

Comment: David, I installed Ubuntu 22.04 LTS.  Yes there is no GUI and it is booting into console mode but I can't get the lower resolution and 80 x 25 screen

Comment: Vanadium yes the options are limited but using /etc/default/console-setup, unfortunately, makes no difference

Answer (score 1):

To disable graphical login and get a text/getty login, you want to change the default target for systemd:

systemctl set-default multi-user.target

This will not necessarily give you a 80x24 console, changing the console-setup font sizes will assist there.

Similarly, your grub environment (and command line parameters) will control the font selection and any intermediary graphical environments between grub and getty.

You seemed to have both of those issues identified and perhaps even under control, leaving the systemd target the most likely source of your woes.  If you still have problems, please describe exactly which aspect of your boot is causing you problems.

Looking at [Ubuntu running only graphics mode and I cant change to text mode](https://askubuntu.com/questions/1382766/ubuntu-running-only-graphics-mode-and-i-cant-change-to-text-mode?rq=1) and similar suggested related questions may also be productive.